# Squish: how to trigger button action when the button is not in current view

Tags: button, triggers, action, squish

I am having troubles when clicking a button because the test machine resolution is different than the one were the test was created. This causes the application to not have all the buttons in the current view(a scrollbar appears) because they don't fit. Is there a way to trigger the button action, although it is not in the current view, other than scrolling until the button is displayed in the current view?

Comment: Squish supports various GUI technologies, and each to a different extent and level of convenience. Ideally you should not need to concern yourself with scrolling something into view for sake of interacting with it, it should be taken care of for you. But with QtQuick/QML for example that may be a difficult technical problem and thus may not work. So please let us know what kind of of technologies are involved here.

Comment: It is a Java application and it works with SWT.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the vendor of Squish there is support for automatically scrolling the target object into the visible area for SWT, but nesting can make this complicated and error-prone. I suggest to contact the vendor to let them analyze the specific case.

An alternative can be to change the screen resolution for the course of the test replay. Relevant for that:

[Executing external applications](https://kb.froglogic.com/squish/howto/executing-external-applications/)

[Changing, setting screen resolution on Windows](https://kb.froglogic.com/misc/changing-setting-screen-resolution-windows/) (On Linux one can often use "xrandr" to change the screen resolution.)

Another alternative could be to access the API of the GUI objects from the test scripts, to instruct the parent/container (and potentially all their parents) to scroll the target object into view yourself. [Here](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0280__SWT/Scrollawidgetintoviewonfocusin.htm) is an example of that (in plain Java), which is using [ScrolledComposite.setOrigin(int,int)](https://help.eclipse.org/2019-12/nftopic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/swt/custom/ScrolledComposite.html#setOrigin(int,int)).